# I want to join two dataframe columns but not getting desired ouput

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe one is x and another is total which have a column pop but has datetime as index

data of the dataframe are of this type:

total[pop]  dataframe data:

```
DateTime

2016-08-20 12:00:00      NaN

2016-08-21 00:00:00      NaN

2016-08-21 12:00:00      NaN

2016-08-22 00:00:00      NaN

2016-08-22 12:00:00      NaN
```

x Dataframe
           x

```
0      1

1      2

2      3

3      4

4      5
```

i wrote this query:

```
data_Window=pd.concat([x.x,Total.pop[index_start:index_end].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
```

where index start and index end has some integer value to join some range of data with x.

the output i got:

```
       0   1

0      1 NaN

1      2 NaN

2      3 NaN

3      4 NaN

4      5 NaN

5      6 NaN

6      7 NaN

7      8 NaN
```

even for some pop column where some value is present it is showing nan(i had just post some rows for example both dataframe has more than 100 rows)

output I want :

```
index  x  pop

0      1   2.09

1      2    1.30

2      3    2.10
```

Comment: what is `2.09,1.30,..`

Comment: @pyd these are the values pop column contain as i told it has more than 100 rows  and i had just post some rows of data.

Comment: so you want to drop all NaN and update with valid value? your sample data is not sufficient to understand what you're asking

Comment: it has both nan and some float values i just want to concatenate the two dataframe x and total[pop] but as my dataframe named total has a datetime column as index i'm not able to concatenate them

Comment: Can you post code to generate sample input datasets? It is very unclear from your question what operations you actually want to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're trying to join x to total without aligning the index at all. If so, you could just assign the values to a new column directly:

```
In [18]: df['pop'] = x.x.values

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
                     pop
DateTime
2016-08-20 12:00:00    1
2016-08-21 00:00:00    2
2016-08-21 12:00:00    3
2016-08-22 00:00:00    4
2016-08-22 12:00:00    5
```

Comment: i want to join pop to x but doen't want datetime to be my index in the result i only want x values and pop values to be combined but doesn't want to remove my datetime column as index from the total dataframe as i have some another operations to be carried out and that type of index would be really helpful for that. so is there any other way to do it?

Comment: can you modify your question to include an example of what you want the results to look like? I don't know what you're what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for modifying the question, but I still don't understand how you want to use the datetime. Where should the index come from? Do you really just want to put x.x.values and df.pop.values next to each other? In that case, `pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([x.x.values, df.pop.values]).T, columns=['x', 'pop'])` should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question right. This should help.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2014', '2015'], 'quarter': ['q1', 'q2']})
```

[image]

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['2', '5'], 'quarter': ['q1', 'q2']})
```

[image]

```
new_data= pd.concat([df['Year'],df1['month']],axis=1)
```

[image]

May be this solves your problem.